# Measurement of error and outliers

Tags: outliers

Let's assume we collected a data set describing account balances at the end of the month. For each individual, $vo$  is the observed value, and $ve$ the expected value (eg, account balances are assumed to be normally distributed). Values can therefore span from negative, to zero, to extreme values.

The most common way of measuring the deviation from a given distribution for each person would be :

$e = \frac{vo - ve}{|ve|}$

Although this formula is simple and convenient, it however poses a major problem :

1. It is ***highly sensitive to values around 0***, which leads to absurd error rates around $ve = 0$. A shame for our example, in which a lot of account balances are around 0 at the end of the month. Plotting such error rates also creates a spike around 0, crushing the rest of the histogram. A $log(|e|)$ transform helps, but still creates a non sensical spike around 0.
2. It loses sensitivity as $ve$ and $vo$ increase in absolute value. ***Outliers in extreme values are less likely to get picked up.***

Which leads me to my two questions :

1. Are there more useful formulas to measure deviation from a given distribution ?
2. Are there any other useful transformations, other than the $log$ transformation which can help identify outliers ?

Comment: The Kolmogorov Smirnov test can be used to assess deviation from a given probability distribution. However, be careful with testing for a deviation from multiple distributions as (1) the chance of a significant deviation increases with the number of tests, and (2) the probability distribution with the lowest deviation is not necessarily more likely to be the more probable distribution. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test